# How to import data from a .csv file and convert it to java script objects?

Tags: javascript, object, csv, file-io

I have a .csv file with generic data.

I was wondering how I could use javascript to parse this file and organize them into javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-CSV may work for you:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

**Features**

> - Convert a CSV String to an array
> - Convert a multi-line CSV string to a 2D array
> - Convert a multi-line CSV string to an array of objects (ie header:value pairs)
> - Convert an array of values to CSV (under development)
> - Convert an array of objects to CSV (under development)
> - Hooks/Callbacks to extend the default parsing process
> - Customizable delimiter (default: ") and separator (default: ,) characters
> - Node.js support (ie CommonJS importing and async callback support)

Comment: This is basically what I've been playing around with for the past few days. I've gotten it to create a javascript object from hard coded data. But I can't seem to be able to do it from an external file.

Comment: You could get the data using an ajax request depending on your setup. Or if you're using NodeJS you can open the file with a file handle and run it through the functions.